# How can I define color palette in my Wordpress Dashboard and use it within my CSS code?

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

I am using Bootstrap to make my HTML templates, and I want to override some theme variables from Bootstrap. But I would like to define these colors in the Wordpress Dashboard and bind them to my Bootstrap theme, so nobody has to know CSS to change the color theme.

I tried using a simple plugin for defining a color palette in my dashboard called [Central Color Palette](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kt-tinymce-color-grid/), and I have some colors defined there, but I don't know if there is any way to access them in my main CSS file where I would override the Bootstrap variables, I tried in every way but the variables just weren't recognized. I saw somewhere else in a plugin that it is possible somehow.

I would like to know if anybody knows a fix with this plugin, or knows a better plugin that doesn't add lots of useless extra features.

Comment: With the SASS variables Bootstrap uses for basic configuration, this would make rather little sense - because then you would have to _compile_ it again after every change. CSS variables would be the way to go - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/css-variables/

Comment: @CBroe My question is not about how bootstrap works, though I should look into what you said as well to see if I made a mistake there. My problem is how do I gain access in my Bootstrap overrides to the colors I defined in my Dashboard

Comment: You generate a snippet of CSS code, based on the values from your dashboard, that overwrites these CSS variables - basically duplicating the parts of the `_root.scss` file, that you are interested in changing. As long as your snippet is embedded after the BS style sheets, it will overwrite these "defaults" then. https://jsfiddle.net/qy1c3am7/

Comment: @CBroe ok so from what I understand, the plugin doesn't embed the new CSS variables somewhere in :root so I can just reference them in my code. I have to add these CSS variables in the Additional CSS snippet from the dashboard to be available in my CSS code.

Comment: I don't know what exactly that plugin does, but it sounds to me as if its purpose rather was to configure some colors WP itself already handles "dynamically", without any real connection to Bootstrap. _"I have to add these CSS variables in the Additional CSS snippet from the dashboard to be available in my CSS code."_ - manually? But then you will have to update that again every time you make a change in the plugin settings. Would make more sense to try and automate this via the plugin API then, https://kungtiger.github.io/central-color-palette/